# Looping the same label to multi document

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a corpus of text documents with given data frame:

```
       Category    Document
 0        a           1
 1      None          2
 2      None          3
 3      None          4
...     ...          ...
10      None          9
```

Current coding:

```py
inputfile = open("file.txt", 'r')
corpus = [w for w in inputfile]
label = ['a']
corpus_df = {'Document': corpus, 'Category': label}
corpus_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(corpus_df, orient='index')
print corpus_df.transpose()
```

My question is how can i make the other documents have the same category as D1?

Comment: IIUC need `df['Category'] = df['Category'].ffill()` ?

Comment: @jezrael thanks for the suggestion but the error states that the 'list' object has no attribute 'ffill'